# Is it possible to toggle "container" and "container-fluid" only using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like toggle the class `container` and `container-fluid` using a button (for change width of layout). It is easy using JavaScript / jQuery, but, is possible only with Bootstrap 4?. Collapse component maybe?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a pre-existing Bootstrap CSS class or data attribute that will allow you to toggle between the two? Like how `data-dismiss="modal"` closes modals?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/ <--- I would like with a button, change "container" to "container-fluid" (and vice versa) without javascript. I don't know if it is possible?

Comment: Hi. Do you want to do this when changing the viewport width?

Comment: pressing a button

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see to do this is as follows, but it *does* use javascript:

```js
const containerElement = document.getElementById("my-container");

function toggleClass() {
  const newClass = containerElement.className == "container" ? "container-fluid" : "container";
  containerElement.className = newClass;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="my-container" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      Hello there
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="toggleClass()">toggle classes</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question was without JS.